# Arduino Protothreads seem to be shared by two buttons

Tags: oop, arduino, protothread

I ran into a problem regarding the Protothreading library in Arduino. I have created a `Button` class, which represents a hardware button. Now the idea is that you can attach a `ButtonListener` to it, which listens to the button. If a button is pressed, then the `clicked()` function is called.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <pt.h>

class ButtonListener {
    public:
        virtual void clicked() = 0;
        virtual void longClicked() = 0;
        virtual void tapped(int) = 0;
};

class Button {

    static const int RECOIL_TIME = 200;
    static const int LONG_CLICK_LENGTH = 1000;

    private:
        int _pin;
        ButtonListener *_listener;
        struct pt _thread;
        unsigned long _timestamp = 0;

        int listenerHook(struct pt *pt) {
            PT_BEGIN(pt);
            this->_timestamp = 0;
            while (true) {
                PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, millis() - _timestamp > 1);
                _timestamp = millis();
                if (&this->_listener != NULL) {
                    this->listenForClick();
                }
            }
            PT_END(pt);
        }

        void listenForClick() {
            boolean longClicked = true;
            int state = digitalRead(this->_pin);
            if (state == HIGH) {
                unsigned long timestamp = millis();
                while (true) {
                    longClicked = millis() - timestamp > LONG_CLICK_LENGTH;
                    state = digitalRead(this->_pin);
                    if (state == LOW) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (&this->_listener != NULL) {
                    if (longClicked) {
                        (*this->_listener).longClicked();
                    }
                    else {
                        (*this->_listener).clicked();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public:
        Button(int pin) {
            this->_pin = pin;
        }

        void init() {
            pinMode(this->_pin, OUTPUT);
            PT_INIT(&this->_thread);
        }

        void setListener(ButtonListener *listener) {
            this->_listener = listener;
        }

        void listen() {
            this->listenerHook(&this->_thread);
        }
};
```

Now I've created two implementations of `ButtonListener`:

```
class Button12Listener : public ButtonListener {
    public:
        void clicked() {
            Serial.println("Button 12 clicked!");
        }
}
```

The other implementation is a `Button13Listener` and prints "Button 13 clicked!"

Then let's run the code:

```
// Instantiate the buttons
Button button12(12);
Button button13(13);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    button12.init();
    button13.init();

    // Add listeners to the buttons
    button12.setListener(new Button12Listener());
    button13.setListener(new Button13Listener());
}

void loop() {
    while (true) {
        // Listen for button clicks
        button12.listen();
        button13.listen();
    }
    Serial.println("Loop ended.");
    delay(60000);
}
```

I expect "Button 12 clicked!" when I click the button on pin 12, and "Button 13 clicked!" when I click the button on pin 13.

But when I try to click on any of the buttons, it is randomly printing "Button 12 clicked!" or "Button 13 clicked!" no matter what button I press.

It look like the protothreads are shared among the buttons or something.

If I check in which order the buttons are called, like this:

```
button12.listen();
Serial.println("listen12");
button13.listen();
Serial.println("listen13");
```

then the following outputs:

```
12
13
12
13
12
12
```

Thát seems okay.

So what's the problem? What have I missed?

Comment: Unrelated, but isn't timestamp in listenerHook zeroed on every function call? Coming from C, where if you want to retain local variable value between pt calls you must make it static in pt function. I don't know if static variable in class function is shared between objects. EDIT: it seems that you should move timestamp to private class member and move it's initialization after PT_BEGIN to avoid zeroing.

Comment: I've edited the question. Do you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this.

Comment: It doesn't help... :-(

Comment: As i said, it was unrelated fix. Try add some prints in listenForClick, especially in this while(1) loop. Print this->_pin, it should print button number in loop while you are pressing it. Your code blocks on press.

Comment: Hi, have you found the cause of error?

Comment: I have not found the error, but I suspect it has something to do with hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely eliminating the whole point of protothreads by having that while(true) loop in listenForClick. I would do it like this:

```
PT_BEGIN(thr); 
while(1){
  // ensure that the pin is low when you start
  PT_WAIT_UNTIL(thr, digitalRead(pin) == LOW); 
  // wait until pin goes high
  PT_WAIT_UNTIL(thr, digitalRead(pin) == HIGH); 
  // insert delay here for minimum time the pin must be high
  this->timeout = millis() + 20; // 20 ms
  // wait until the delay has expired
  PT_WAIT_UNTIL(thr, this->timeout - millis() > 0); 
  // wait until the pin goes low again
  PT_WAIT_UNTIL(thr, digitalRead(pin) == LOW); 
  // call the click callback
  this->clicked(); 
}
PT_END(thr);
```

Then just call this thread repeatedly.

NOTE: when you have buttons connected, you would usually have pullup on the pin and have button connected between the pin and ground - so the pin is LOW when the button is down and high when it is not being pressed. This would certainly be the case on an arduino. So you would have to change the code above to wait for a negative pulse instead of a positive one. :)